# Excel Interop build errors with .NET 5

Tags: c#, excel-interop, .net-5

I am porting a .Net Framework 4.7.2 project to .NET 5 and have Excel.Interop build errors that Intellisense has no problem with. I have:

1. Created a new .NET WPF project
2. Update the TargetFramework property in the .csproj file from .netcore3.1 to net5.0-windows
3. Copied my classes over into the new project
4. Added a reference to the Excel 16.0 Object Library
5. Changed the Copy Local property of the Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dependency to Yes and changed the Embed Interop Types property to Yes as well
6. Started a build

The build fails with Interop errors like "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Value'" even though those errors in Intellisense go away after I update the Copy Local and Embed Interop Types properties.

Following the build, if I double-click on each of the build errors, the class file opens and Intellisense considers the error resolved: it disappears from the list and the red line under the code disappears as well.

I see Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in the project Dependencies --> COM expandable items in the Solution Explorer, but when I right click on the Solution, do Properties, and look at Project Dependencies for my project, nothing is listed. Is this a problem? Would a COM reference be listed in Solution Properties --> Project Dependencies?

I was under the impression that the Office Interop libraries would be compatible with .NET 5 and that I am setting things up correctly. Why is does Intellisense think things are fine but build errors result?

**Things I've tried**

- Restarting Visual Studio and my computer
- Removing the reference and re-adding it
- Cleaning and rebuilding the solution
- Deleting the bin and obj folders in the project

Comment: You see, you can't just port a library (especially interop one) just by moving files and changing .NET version. Also, screenshot with full error name would be useful.

Comment: The errors are all instances of the basic C# Missing Assembly or Reference error: 'X' does not contain a definition for 'Y', and no extension method Y could be found. (Are you missing an assembly or reference?) So Intellisense seems to be detecting the added reference, but the project is building without it.

Comment: That sounds like.. Intellisense and MSBuild are analyzing different target frameworks.

Comment: That's an insightful way of wording it @Vyacheslav, I'll look into that. A similar thought I had: I'm not sure how compatibility with different Object Library versions are determined. Is there any chance that .NET 5 is compatible with Excel Interop, but the actual detail there is that only, say, Office 2019 and above's libraries were updated? Something like that?

Comment: We have Office 2016, which uses Object Library 16.0.